# Single vs Multiple UIImage Caches

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uicollectionview, uiimage

I'm making an app that comes stock with lots of high-res images which are initally displayed in various collection views based on which tab is selected, similar to Instagram. Even though all the images come with app I've found that caching the UIImages asynchronously in a simple NSMutableDictionary, as oppose to reloading them every time, speeds up the collection views UI a ton. Right now I have one image cache that handles all the images in the app, even though they are spread out over multiple view controllers/collection views and are of various sizes. If any of these view controllers get a memory warning the cache is cleared.

My question is: is this an ideal setup, or would it make more sense to have a separate image cache for each view controller that only handles the images within its respective collection view? My thinking is this way if view controller #3 gets a memory warning, only its image cache will be cleared allowing view controllers #1 and #2 to retain their smooth UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something better when you want to cache something, the right object is [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscache), it works as a dictionary, but it has a lot of advantages:

> The NSCache class incorporates various auto-eviction policies, which
>   ensure that a cache doesn’t use too much of the system’s memory. If
>   memory is needed by other applications, these policies remove some
>   items from the cache, minimizing its memory footprint.
>  You can add,
>   remove, and query items in the cache from different threads without
>   having to lock the cache yourself. 
> Unlike an NSMutable​Dictionary
>   object, a cache does not copy the key objects that are put into it.

About you question I think that there is not a specific answer. If you manage the cache correctly you can use just one, but I would create one for each collection view I use, to avoid sharing information.